# Minlength error in template driven form in angular 8

Tags: typescript, angular8

I am getting below error when i click the submit button.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'minlength' of null
```

I do not know why i am getting this error.So How to resolve this issue.

app.component.html:

```
<form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && onSubmit()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="categoryName">Category Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="categoryName" [(ngModel)]="cate.categoryName" minlength="5" #categoryname="ngModel" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && categoryName.invalid }" required/>
                <div *ngIf="f.submitted && categoryName.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
                    <div *ngIf="categoryName.errors.required">
                        Category Name is required
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="categoryName?.touched && categoryName?.errors.minlength" class="invalid-feedback">
                    Category Name must be at least 5 characters long.
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Seems like `categoryName.errors` is null.

Comment: @VLAZ: How to avoid that error message?

Comment: I don't know Angular well. My best guess is that you either find the reason why `.errors` is null and fix it, or add another null guard `categoryName?.errors?.minlength`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you removed the origin of the error, I'm assuming the error is coming from

This line:

```html
<div *ngIf="categoryName?.touched && categoryName?.errors.minlength" class="invalid-feedback">
```

Here `categoryName?.errors` is null and you tried to access `minlength` on this null value.

To avoid this error, add a `?` operator before `.minlength` like:

```html
<div *ngIf="categoryName?.touched && categoryName?.errors?.minlength" class="invalid-feedback">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngIf="categoryName.touched && categoryName.errors?.['minlength']" ></div>
```